# Requirements could not be resolved personal repository

Tags: composer-php

Anybody can help me solve this issue? I'm trying to add a dependency on a personal repository. I didn't have any issues with my other repositories, but I have issues with this one.

Here is the composer.json file of the personal repository :

```
{
    "name": "bundle-name-1",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    ...
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    ...
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the composer.json file of the main project :

```
{
    "name": "bundle-name-2",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/yaml": "*",
        "bundle-name-1": "~0.9.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": [
        {"type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://git@stash.domainname.com:8999/core/bundlename1repository.git"}
    ],
    ...
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    ...
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I've removed autoload and scripts for both.

The composer message is :

don't install bundle-name-1 v0.9.3|remove bundle-name-2 dev-master
Installation request for bundle-name-1 ~0.9.2 -> satisfiable by bundle-name-1[v0.9.2, v0.9.3].

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the "replace" clause. It was added automatically when creating the symfony skeleton and my bundle wasn't replacing any of these.

Solution :

- Remove the "replace" clause from the "composer.json".
- Run "composer update"